# How does a SpringBoot controller know to return a mustache template instead of a String

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mustache

I'm walking through a [tutorial on Spring Boot using Kotlin](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/). I'm new to Kotlin and Spring, though I've already worked in a couple of different MVC style frameworks in other languages so get the gist.

Something that I don't get as I work through this tutorial is how in these controller methods:

```
package com.example.blog

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.ui.set
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping

@Controller
class HtmlController(private val repository: ArticleRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun blog(model: Model): String {
        model["title"] = "Blog"
        model["articles"] = repository.findAllByOrderByAddedAtDesc().map {
            it.render()
        }
        return "blog"
    }
}
```

Where we see `return "blog"` at the end Spring knows to return a mustache template with the provided model.

I would have expected something like `return MustacheView("blog", model)`(I know that's not a real class or method, just psudocoding to exemplify) or something like that where you're explicitly saying "hey return this as a mustache template and not just the string `blog`"..

I'm sure there's some magic behind the scenes where spring says "oh hey, you have the mustache dependency installed, when you return this string from a controller you must be referring to a template name", but I can't see in the documentation where that's spelled out.

It's not completely necessary to know to finish the tutorial, but it feels like a bit of unexplained magic at the moment and I'd like to know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return a `String`, it is used as a view name. This view name is then [resolved into a `View` implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/web.html#mvc-viewresolver).

In the case of Mustache, Spring Boot auto-configures a [`MustacheViewResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7a7050879cdfd978a63eebc49e378e9029777ccc/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/view/MustacheViewResolver.java) bean. This bean is then picked up by Spring MVC and used to turn your `"blog"` into a `MustacheView` backed by your Mustache template. It is then combined with the `Model` that was passed into your controller method and rendered.

Comment: Ah awesome. thanks for the explanation and the documentation links. This makes sense and along the lines of what I figured was happening, but it's def good to see the documentation. I appreciate the points in the right direction and I'm diving through from here.